# Ignoring java compilation and version control folders in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, directory, version-control

Kubuntu 13.10.

Working directly in ~/Ubuntu One folder, where I have my Java projects under ~/Ubuntu One/java-projects.

I want to ignore compilation and version control folders: classes, dist, .git, .svn and the like.

Created ~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf which contains:

```
[__main__]
ignore = \A.*/build\Z 
         \A.*/target\Z
         \A.*/dist\Z 
         \A.*/classes\Z 
         \A.*/lib\Z 
         \A.*/some/other/folders/to/ignore\Z 
         \A.*\..*\Z
```

Restarted daemon and reboot, but syncdaemon.conf seems to be "ignored" by U1 and nothing is ignored. I have tried different regular expressions but syncdaemon.conf still seems to be ignored.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify `.*/` as a prefix to directory names. If you want to ignore directories named `classes` for example, then simply use `\Aclasses\Z` as the expression. You also cannot ignore explicit paths, as only the base name of the path will be compared to the expression. Thus if you want to ignore `~/Ubuntu One/some/folder` you will have to only ignore `\Afolder\Z`, which will ignore anything in Ubuntu One, with the name of `folder`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that 'syncdaemon.conf' is not even read. I have tried using \Aclasses\Z regex style but still these folders are synchronized. Hidden folders are also uploaded. I need 'some/folder' because I need to ignore 'folder' inside 'some', not any 'folder'. Using Kubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be read? If the file isn't being read, then it is a bug and is off topic (you should file a bug report instead). Anything that isn't ignored will be synchronized, regardless of whether it starts with `.` or not. And as I stated, you cannot ignore full or relative paths, but only immediate file or directory names.

Comment: I'm just a single user who asks before submitting a bug report. Probably I'm doing something wrong (probably something obvious) but I have no idea what it might be and I have no much time to keep testing. If I finally submit a bug report I will link it here.